# Drupal 7/Views - Showing similar content with the same tag(s) when adding a new piece of content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I'm wondering if when creating a new piece of content (say, an Article), is it possible to show similar pieces of content (which have the same tag(s) as the content you are creating) so that the content creator can pick these items to use as related content.

In other words, it will show related content in the admin view (say, as a list) when you are creating a new piece of content (and not in the normal site view that everyone sees).

The list of related content would need to be ordered by most terms matched.

Thanks, Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Views, [similar_by_terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms), [similar](http://drupal.org/project/similar) and other modules provide that functionality. See how to create such a block with views at this article http://www.metachunk.com/blog/adding-related-content-view-drupal-7

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your answer.  I'm trying to create this functionality in the admin tool when you're adding content, e.g. at /admin/node/add/article, rather than on the main website itself.

Comment: In this case you will need the same views under node form (node/add/article) as also as an ajax based button to get the values of the taxonomy terms you set before you submit the Save button. An alternative way is to force users press the "Preview" button before submit so the views can get the taxonomy terms from node.

Comment: @JamieUS Did this answer solve your problem? If so please give some feedback (upvote, select as acceptable).